# Wordpress in Angular (SSR) app return angular 404 page - Nginx

Tags: angular, wordpress, nginx

I have Wordpress blog in an Angular app but when I go to the blog url it return the angular 404 page.

The blog is configured as `example.com/discover`
The error happens when visiting any other blog post as well for example

```
example.com/discover/how-it-works
```

However when I hard refresh the page it load the content.

Here is my nginx config

```
server {
        server_name  domain.com;

        # WordPress site
        location /discover {
                alias /usr/share/nginx/html/blog;

                index index.php;
                if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /discover/index.php last; }

                location ~ \.php$ {
                        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

                        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
                        include       fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                }
        }


        # Website - Angular SSR Application
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name  domain.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

How can I configure the app so that when user visit the blog it will serve from the Wordpress.

Comment: do you get 404 only when you redirects from your Angular app to Wordpress blog or you have the same problem when navigating from one blog page to another? are you using any sort of caching plugin in wordpress? or cdn/cloudflare cache if application? also share your url so we can observe the behavior (only if possible)

Answer (score 0):

Whats happening here is that all requests are being routed to http://127.0.0.1:4000

```
# Website - Angular SSR Application
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
}
```

You should find a way to exclude `/discover` from here.

One way of doing so could be to just reorder your file so `location /` is on top of `location /discover`, that way you first tell your server to reroute all requests to `http://127.0.0.1:4000` and then you override that by saying `/discover` should be handled differently.

Other options might include using regular expresions as described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/562756/how-to-remove-the-path-with-an-nginx-proxy-pass)